# How to do a three-way weighted table in R - similar to wtd.table

Tags: frequency, weighted

I have found MANY questions similar to mine, but either they don't want weighted tables or only want two-ways tables. I am trying to do both.

Using wtd.table, I have the following line of code:

```
wtd.table(fulldata2$income, fulldata2$WIHH, fulldata2$hhsize, weights = fulldata2$WGTP)
```

This output only provides incomes and WIHH weighted. It does not also include hhsize.

Using regular table, I get the correct output in a three-way format, but not weighted.

```
tab <- table(fulldata2$income, fulldata2$WIHH, fulldata2$hhsize)
tab2 <- prop.table(tab)
```

What function can do both three-way and weighted frequency tables? Ideally, also give it in a proportion like prop.table does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here are some sample data (try to include these in your questions, even if it requires creating a sample data set like this). Note that I am using the `tidyverse` packages here:

```
test <-
  tibble(
    var1 = "A"
    , var2 = "b"
    , var3 = "alpha") %>%
  complete(
    var1 = c("A", "B")
    , var2 = c("a", "b")
    , var3 = c("alpha", "beta")) %>%
  mutate(wt = 1:n())
```

So, the data are:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  var1  var2  var3     wt
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 A     a     alpha     1
2 A     a     beta      2
3 A     b     alpha     3
4 A     b     beta      4
5 B     a     alpha     5
6 B     a     beta      6
7 B     b     alpha     7
8 B     b     beta      8
```

The function you are looking for then is `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(wt ~ var1 + var2 + var3
      , data = test)
```

gives:

```
 , , var3 = alpha

    var2
var1 a b
   A 1 3
   B 5 7

, , var3 = beta

    var2
var1 a b
   A 2 4
   B 6 8
```

If you don't need the result to have the `table` class, you can also do this by just using `count` from `dplyr` (part of the `tidyverse`):

```
test %>%
  count(var1, var2, var3
        , wt = wt)
```

gives a tibble (a modified data.frame) with your results:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 4
  var1  var2  var3      n
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>
1 A     a     alpha     1
2 A     a     beta      2
3 A     b     alpha     3
4 A     b     beta      4
5 B     a     alpha     5
6 B     a     beta      6
7 B     b     alpha     7
8 B     b     beta      8
```

And you can then perform whatever calculations you want on it, e.g. the percent within each `var3`:

```
test %>%
  count(var1, var2, var3
        , wt = wt) %>%
  group_by(var3) %>%
  mutate(prop_in_var3 = n / sum(n))
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 8 x 5
# Groups:   var3 [2]
  var1  var2  var3      n prop_in_var3
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <int>        <dbl>
1 A     a     alpha     1       0.0625
2 A     a     beta      2       0.1   
3 A     b     alpha     3       0.188 
4 A     b     beta      4       0.2   
5 B     a     alpha     5       0.312 
6 B     a     beta      6       0.3   
7 B     b     alpha     7       0.438 
8 B     b     beta      8       0.4
```

Comment: I will follow your advice of adding sample data in future questions - thanks. and thanks you so much for xtabs. Problem solved.